Poetry PyTorch dependency exclude cuda as I want to use the system cuda
I have these depencencies:
deepmultilingualpunctuation = "^1.0.1"
In the tree I see it requires torch
deepmultilingualpunctuation 1.0.1 A python package for deep multilingual punctuation prediction.
├── torch >=1.8.1
│   ├── filelock * 
│   ├── fsspec * 
│   ├── jinja2 * 
│   │   └── markupsafe >=2.0 
│   ├── networkx * 
│   ├── nvidia-cublas-cu12 12.1.3.1 
│   ├── nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12 12.1.105 
│   ├── nvidia-cuda-nvrtc-cu12 12.1.105 
│   ├── nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12 12.1.105 

As you can see it includes the nvidia libs. These are already on my system, so I don't want to pull them in all my venvs
I tried adding a torch, extras=[cpu] dependency, but that does not help.
What is the proper solution to let Pytorch use the provided system libs?

I'm not sure how you tell it to use your system libraries for this.
But for example if you want the CPU only version of torch you can do this:
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
torch = { version = ">=2.0.0", source = "pytorch-cpu"}


[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "pytorch"
url = "https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu"
priority = "explicit"

You can see the list of special builds here https://download.pytorch.org/whl/
This link is also helpful https://pytorch.org/get-started/locally/

This works because this version of pytoch does have cuda support baked in

@RobAudenaerde do you mean "does NOT have cuda support"? It's CPU only, so I'm not sure it knows to pick up your system's CUDA install.

No I acutally mean that is HAS cuda-support. (which is not intuitive at all!) See also here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78947332/how-to-install-torch-without-nvidia/78947357#78947357 Just not the cuda library depenencies. Which is exactly what I want to reduce my Docker image size :) Because it already contains these libs on the OS level

As of torch 2.5.1, it no longer seems to work like this :(
